# Image scanning not working in Sysdig secure

Tags: ibm-cloud, sysdig

I am working on Sysdig-secure to enable Image Scanning. I have followed all the steps to enable image scanning (https://docs.sysdig.com/en/image-scanning.html#UUID-4db6c413-043d-8661-7599-c12c0ce0d7cf_UUID-1b8910ba-b5f9-4150-9854-67419de3f302). On IBMCloud,our plan is Graduated Tier - Sysdig Secure + Monitor which covers both Sysdig secure and Monitor. Still, I am not able to scan images of my openshift cluster whereas monitor is working fine. Please helpO

Comment: I also tried to install node image analyzer on the same namespace as the sysdig agent to enable auto image scanning following Daemonset install(https://docs.sysdig.com/en/scan-running-images.html#UUID-b3b07aa6-db02-eb58-050f-15c9e053bb64_section-idm4575656638939231739788462586) The install is failing with the pods giving the following error:

Comment: tried to install node image analyzer on the same namespace as the sysdigagent to enable auto image scanning following https://docs.sysdig.com/en/scan-running-images.html#UUID-b3b07aa6-db02-eb58-050f-15c9e053bb64_section-idm4575656638939231739788462586.It is failing with the pods giving the following error: ShouldScanImage: ApiV1ImagesImageDigestGet returns an error calling for image &{quay.io/sysdig/node-image-analyzer:latest sha256:unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock 863764576 containers-storage}."Can not contact Analysis Manager: image quay.io/sysdig/node-image-analyzer:latest  is refused"}